# C# Search and Set Node Values

Tags: c#, xml, string, nodes

With my other question: [Showing Multiple XML Data Entries With the Same Node Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672750/c-showing-multiple-xml-data-entires-with-the-same-node-value)

I have one more question, in the part:

```
XmlNodeList allNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Lessons/Lesson[Date='01/01/2010']");
```

Is there a way to put a string with a value in it (that I already have setup) in the part '01/01/2010'?

Comment: do you mean use a variable as opposed to a literal value?

var myDate = "'01/01/2010'";

and then 

XmlNodeList allNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Lessons/Lesson[Date=myDate]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple change would do...

```
string yourstring = "01/01/2010";

XmlNodeList allNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Lessons/Lesson[Date='" + yourstring + "']");
```