# Displaying XML Data Entries With the Same Node Value

Tags: c#, xml

ok first off i am fully aware of this question" [Showing Multiple XML Data Entries With the Same Node Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672750/c-sharp-showing-multiple-xml-data-entires-with-the-same-node-value) " but it doesn't answer my question

ok so to start off this is my xml

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
  <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
  <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Wed"/>
    <low data="57"/>
    <high data="68"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
    <condition data="Partly Cloudy"/>
  </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Thu"/>
      <low data="57"/>
      <high data="68"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_rain.gif"/>
      <condition data="Chance of Rain"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Fri"/>
      <low data="59"/>
      <high data="68"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif"/>
      <condition data="Cloudy"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Sat"/>
      <low data="59"/>
      <high data="68"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif"/>
      <condition data="Cloudy"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
  </weather>
</xml_api_reply>
```

and as you can see there are multiple `forecast_conditions` and what im wanting to do is display each day in its own string like so...

```
string day1;
string day2;
string day3;
string day4;

day1 = "Wed";
day2 = "Thu";
day3 = "Fri";
day4 = "Sat";
```

but since all the heading nodes are the same ( `forecast_conditions` ) im a bit confused on how to do this

This is how im geting it so far

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlConditions.SelectNodes("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions"))
{
    Conditions condition = new Conditions();
    condition.City = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information/city").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
    condition.Condition = node.SelectSingleNode("condition").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
    condition.High = node.SelectSingleNode("high").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
    condition.Low = node.SelectSingleNode("low").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
    condition.DayOfWeek = node.SelectSingleNode("day_of_week").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
    conditions.Add(condition);
}
```

and this

```
public class Conditions
{
    public string DayOfWeek
    {
        get { return dayOfWeek; }
        set { dayOfWeek = value; }
    }
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ if you have your XML stored in an `XDocument` object. I haven't tested this exactly but try something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream_of_your_xml);
var allConditions = from forecast_conditions in doc.Descendants("forecast_conditions") 
            select new Conditions()
            {
                DayOfWeek = forecast_conditions.Element("day_of_week").Attribute("data").Value,
                Low = forecast_conditions.Element("low").Attribute("data").Value
                //Do the same for your other values
            };
List<Conditions> theConditions = (List<Conditions>) allConditions;
```